# How do I select from a subquery using the Django ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have a table that is meant to be insert only.  It has columns for `id`, `object_id`, and `user_id`.  When you update a record, instead of updating the row, you create a new record with a matching `object_id`.

I'm trying to pull all records that match a given `user_id` with the highest `id` for each individual `object_id`.

I can do what I'm attempting to describe with a subquery like so:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = 100 ORDER BY object_id, id DESC) adr_table GROUP BY object_id
```

I've tried using the `raw()` method, but it returns a `RawQuerySet` object and I'm trying to feed it to a form that needs a `QuerySet`.

I'd ideally like to get rid of the `raw()` and just use the Django ORM, but if that isn't possible, how can I convert the `RawQuerySet` to a regular `QuerySet`?

Comment: I failed to mention previously, but I am using MySQL for this project, so I am unable to use distinct().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Model.objects.filter(user_id=100).values('object_id').annotate(Max('id'))
```

Comment: I believe this is very close to what I'm looking for but I think I may have abstracted away a little too much in an attempt to simplify my problem.  The table does have other fields and my hope is that this returns the model objects rather than a dict.  The form that I'm passing it to uses the __unicode__ method to know what to display on the form.

Comment: I ended up just doing this to create a list of the ids and then fed that to a filter on a second query.

Not pretty but it works.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this late but yea, you could use `__in` on a list of ids. I thought you want to preserve the max id as well but sounds like it's not the case, so that's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right the table structure is:

```
----------------------------
|           Table          |
----------------------------
| id | user_id | object_id |
----------------------------
| 1  |   100   |    10     |
----------------------------
| 2  |   100   |    20     |
----------------------------
| 3  |   200   |    80     |
----------------------------
| 4  |   100   |    80     |
----------------------------
| 5  |   100   |    10     |
----------------------------
```

And the result of your query should be:

```
----------------------------
|           Table          |
----------------------------
| id | user_id | object_id |
----------------------------
| 4  |   100   |    80     |
----------------------------
| 2  |   100   |    20     |
----------------------------
| 5  |   100   |    10     |
----------------------------
```

Then try [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct), like so:

```
Model.objects.filter(user_id=100).order_by('-object_id', '-id').distinct('object_id')
```

this should return `QuerySet` with your records with `user_id` equal 100, then ordered by `object_id` first and `id` second in descending order, and due to `distinct` on `object_id` only the first record for each same `object_id` will be take, which with the ordering specified will be the one with the highest `id`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am forced to use MySQL on this project, so distinct() is not available to me.